# How do lower frequencies change differently than higher ones as they travel?

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency

I read the following on the internet:

**"This means that as sound travels, its relative frequency content alters making the low frequencies more prominent at greater distances, creating low frequency noise problems.** As a result of this it is not uncommon for complaints to be received from residences located far away from a problem source and over quite a wide area."

What does it mean?  I don't remember much about physics at this point, so please bear with it.

Comment: What was in the sentence or paragraph before this one? What does *this* refer to? That should be what the author is telling you causes these results. A link to the full text you've quoted from would help.

Comment: Your question is most probably related to the attenuation of sound against propagation distance. If this is the case I believe [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/509600/220866), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/134791/220866), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/224250/220866) and possibly [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/527333/220866) (the last part of it) answer will help you understand the phenomena.

Comment: @ZaellixA I think you are right, but the phrasing "relative frequency content alters " confused me and I didn't take it in context